# Query runs in Hibernate using WAS 6 but fails in WAS 7

Tags: oracle, hibernate, websphere

I have a query:

```
select TO_DATE(TRUNC(table1.DATE_SENT)) AS "dateSent"
```

Datatype of `DATE_SENT` is : `Timezone with TimeStamp`

This works in WAS 6.1 but in WAS 7.0 I get :

> No dialect mapping for JDBC type : -9

I suspect this is because of the different hibernate implementations between WAS 6 and WAS 7.
But how do i solve this? We need to move to WAS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the java.sql.Types.

See what is the int constant that corresponds to -9.

That should tell you what is the type that it is complaining about.

You might have to write some custom code if there is no native support for that data type.

I don't have a WAS 7 or a JDK 6 in front of me to help out.

Check this one out to get some ideas:

http://javaalert.wordpress.com/2008/05/31/no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-7/

HTH

Manglu